# C# float.Parse String

Tags: c#, .net, string, substring, type-conversion

I'm new in C# and need to read `float` values `(x, y, z)` from file.
It looks like:

> 0 -0.01 -0.002
>
> 0.000833333333333 -0.01 -0.002

If Iam trying

```
float number = float.Parse("0,54"); // it works well, but
float number = float.Parse("0.54"); // gains exepction.
```

My code for reading values from each line (could be bugged):

```
int begin = 0;
int end = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < tempLine.Length; i++)
{
    if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(tempLine.ElementAt(i)))
    {
        end = i;
        float value = float.Parse(tempLine.Substring(begin, end));
        begin = end;
        System.Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

Someone could help?

Comment: I'd split the string by space and then loop the array with `float.Parse` etc

Answer (score 42):

[`float.Parse(string)` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2thct5cb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) uses your current culture settings by default. Looks like your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)'s [`NumberDecimalSeparator` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is `,` not `.`

That's why you get `FormatException` in your `"0.54"` example.

As a solution, you can use a culture have `.` as a `NumberDecimalSeparator` like [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as a second parameter in `Parse` method, or you can [`.Clone()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.clone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) your `CurrentCulture` and set it's `NumberDecimalSeparator` property to `.`

```
float number = float.Parse("0.54", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or

```
var culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
float number = float.Parse("0.54", culture);
```

Answer (score 8):

It seems your culture uses comma as the decimal separator. Try parsing it with `InvariantCulture`:

```
var value = float.Parse(tempLine.Substring(begin, end), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

In addition to this, the way you're parsing the lines is more complicated than it should be. You can just split the line instead of trying to deal with indices:

```
foreach(var str in tempLine.Split())  
{
    float value = float.Parse(str, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Comment: Ah I was going to suggest the Split but was think more of a float[] as the output so no need for any loops.
`float[] temp = float.Parse(tempLine.Split() );`

Comment: sorry this works
`float[] temp = tempLine.Split().Select(x => float.Parse(x)).ToArray();`